# Regex vb.net match numbers with commas, \ and spaces

Tags: vb.net

I am really close, I just need assistance with the first part of the regex.

Example of lines: Var=Gibberish unsigned 0,2 /e:Enum014 /ln:"Meaning" /number:695 /Gibberish:87

Var=Gibberish unsigned 2,2 /e:Gibberish /ln:"Meaning" /number:696 /Gibberish:87

"" --> total of 10 lines. For some reason, it only returns the last two lines properly and skips the first 8 (all lines are on there own line, cascading down, no spaces in a txt file).

Var=Gibberish unsigned 56,4 /e:Gibberish /ln:"Meaning" /number:4206 /Gibberish:87

Var=Gibberish unsigned 60,4 /e:Enum234 /ln:"Meaning" /number:4207 /Gibberish:88

```
                 Do
                    line = reader.ReadLine
                    If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
                    m = Regex.Match(line, ".* ([0-9]+),([0-9]+) /ln:\""(.*)\"" /number:(\d+) .*")
                    If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
                        startPosition = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                        Debug.Print(startPosition)
                        totalLength = m.Groups(2).ToString()
                        Debug.Print(totalLength)
                        ln = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                        Debug.Print(ln)
                        number = m.Groups(2).ToString()
                        Debug.Print(number)
                    End If
                Loop Until line = ""
```

Output: 56 4 Meaning 4206  |  60 4 Meaning 4207.

Expected 0 2 Meaning 695  |  2 2 Meaning 696 | "rest of txt file"

Comment: `.*?(\d+,\d+).*?\"(.+?)\".*?(\d+)`

Comment: Hmm, `(.+?)` is giving me an error: "Identifier expected. Expression expected the ? cannot be used here". If I hover over the '.', it says, "Leading '.' or ! can only appear inside of a with statement. Identifier expected." I tried doing `.*?(\d+,\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+)` to fix it but that didn't return anything.

Comment: @Jimi, So `?(\d+,\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+)` works, but it puts unsigned on same line (i.e., 2,2). I would like it to be 2 next line 2.

Comment: @Jimi, `.*?(\d+)(,\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+) .*` I fixed it being next to each other, but now it is 2    new line ,2 - how do I remove that pesky comma? ---- figured it out `.*?(\d+),(\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+) .*`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jimi, the answer is below.

`.*?(\d+),(\d+).*?\""(.+?)\"".*?(\d+) .*`

Comment: Not related to the specific question, but I like [The RegEx Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/), a piece of Windows software that let's you experiment with actual data + a regular expression and shows the results on-the-fly.